# Ruby AWS Lambda - 502 Bad Gateway from Application Load Balancer when returning binary content

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, base64, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an AWS lambda (written in Ruby) that is functioning as a web server.  I access the lambda through an application load balancer.  The following code works well for html, javascript, and css files.

```
{ 
  statusCode: 200, 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => "text/html"
  },
  body: File.open("index.html").read
}
```

I have added code that attempts to return binary data from the Lambda.

```
{
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => 'image/x-icon'
  },
  isBase64Encoded: true,
  body: Base64.encode64(IO.binread("favicon.ico"))
}
```

If I invoke the lambda through the load balancer, I receive a "502 Bad Gateway" response from the load balancer.  The load balancer logs show the following.

```
"error_reason"="LambdaInvalidResponse"
```

If I invoke the lambda from a command line with `aws lambda invoke`, I see my 200 response and the expected response data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Base64.strict_encode64` instead of `Base64.encode64`.

To find the problem, I spun up a Python lambda and made it return the exact same file. I verified that it worked with an ALB, and that the Ruby version did not. Then I used cli to invoke each one (tricky with the binary output), and compared.

Python’s default base64 encoder output the whole chunk without newlines, whereas Ruby's embedded newlines.

According to the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64):

- `strict_encode64` “complies with RFC 4648. No line feeds are added."
- `encode64` "complies with RFC 2045. Line feeds are added to every 60 encoded characters."

I guess the ALB is very picky about its Base-64 encoding!